# Change the height of option tag from select

Tags: css

I have the next component:

```js
 <Select
        mode="multiple"
        placeholder="Inserted are removed"
        value={selectedItems}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
      >
        {filteredOptions.map(item => (
          <Select.Option key={item} value={item}>
            {item}
          </Select.Option>
        ))}
 </Select>
```

In my **demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/hide-already-selected-ant-design-demo-39xfe?file=/index.js:542-889, i added some styles:

```css
.ant-select-item-option-content {
  background-color: red;
}
.ant-select-item-option-active:not(.ant-select-item-option-disabled) {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: auto;
}
```

Why  `height:10px;` does not work? And how to apply 10px of heigth for that selector?

Comment: what is it you want I can see the height is working as expected or I may be missing understanding your question. I can see both Red and Blue height content is increased when `height` is added.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove height:auto:

```
.ant-select-item-option-content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 5px;
}
.ant-select-item-option-active:not(.ant-select-item-option-disabled) {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Or perhaps you need something like this:

```
.ant-select-item-option-content {
  background-color: red;
}
.ant-select-item-option-active:not(.ant-select-item-option-disabled) {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: auto;
}

.ant-select-item-option-active:not(.ant-select-item-option-disabled) .ant-select-item-option-content {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: but does not work, the blue section still the same height,even i change to `5px`

Comment: Then you need set a height in option-content

Answer (score 0):

I checked your link. It seems like there is another style rule thats applying a `min-height:32px;` to the active element.
Either remove that or include `min-height` in your CSS like so:

```
.ant-select-item-option-active:not(.ant-select-item-option-disabled) {
  min-height: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```